# Elementary Set Proofs and the Universe of Discourse

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

I'm trying to understand proofs for set theory, and need some help representing my reasoning for a proof. This is super basic but I want to make sure I definitely understand this before I move on.

Given

$x\in A$

$A\subseteq B$

Prove

$x\in B$

So $A\subseteq B$ is the same as saying $\forall n(n\in A \rightarrow n\in B )$

Is it safe to say that $x$ can be an instance of $n$, if $n$ is all elements in the universe of discourse, and do I need to specify that somehow in a proof? Do I need to specify that $x$ and $n$ are in the same universe or is that implied?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $x \in A$ means that $x$ and $A$ must be in the same universe of discourse, so no specification is needed. Also, in general, the universe of discourse never changes within a single series of statements.

Finally, in set theory, the universe of discourse is usually *everything*. When we say $A \subseteq B$, we don't mean "$A$ is a subset of $B$ as far as the present universe of discourse is concerned", we mean "literally every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$".